# java trouble getting FileReader to work

Tags: java, filereader

root directory is named CopyFile, has directories files and src. files has the text file loremipsum.txt. src has com/example/java/Main.java

this is the code in Main.java

```
package com.example.java;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sourceFile = "files/loremipsum.txt";
        String targetFile = "files/target.txt";

        try (FileReader fReader = new FileReader(sourceFile);
             BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
             FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(targetFile)){

            while (true){
                String line =  bReader.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                } else{
                    writer.write(line + "\n");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("File Copied!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: files/loremipsum.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at com.example.java.Main.main(Main.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: That means the file `files/loremipsum.txt` doesn't exsist

Comment: but its in the directory? .... where is java looking? I even created a folder called files with the text file in the directory of Main.java and that didnt work either

Comment: Has java changed recently? Is it now legal to put code in parentheses following a `try` statement? How does this code even compile?

Comment: You can try `new File("/files/loremipsum.txt").getAbsolutePath();` to get the full path

Comment: @DroidGamer what is the Current Working Directory of your program when you run it?  It may not be what you are assuming it is.

Comment: @JimmyHuch Yes it's legal i thought it wasn't for a while but that just means it will handle the closing and stuff for you.

Comment: It doesn't help that we don't know how you're running this at the moment...

Comment: @3kings - Yes, this is some fancy shmancy stuff.. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Previously we would need a `finally` block to take care of the closing. Looks like I'll be ordering Java from my starbucks this morning :)

Comment: ok im in intellij heres a screen shot http://imgur.com/j6M9r7Q

Comment: @DroidGamer show us your directory.

Comment: Can you show how you start the application (command line, in wich directory, ...) ?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/a83c7h8oh/

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/fyncsuh5h/     also i am running the code from intellij not terminal

Answer (score 1):

If you put this above your variables defining your file locations:

```
File here = new File(".");
System.out.println(here.getAbsolutePath());
```

You'll see that Java is looking for the files at the root directory of your project and **not** anywhere inside `src` or `out`.

So, your project directory tree should look like this (assuming IntelliJ):

```
ProjectName/  
    .idea/
    files/
        loremipsum.txt
        target.txt
    out/
        production/
            ProjectName/
                package.name/
                     Main.class
    src/
        package.name/
                Main.java
    ProjectName.iml
```

Comment: So essentially, from the JVM's perspective; there wasn't a file found; Your file was in the wrong place! https://youtu.be/Pk-B0s0jOwE?t=2m20s

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! What happened is I imported the example code a directory too high when creating the project.

Comment: Please enter your solution as an answer for yourself and in 48 hours accept your answer (or accept my answer <3). [Reference to answering own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)